# Decoupling JavaScript and Html

Tags: javascript

In response to [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539461/any-value-in-javascript-html-decoupling-if-so-how/6539734) on Stack Overflow, I'm attempting a solution to decouple JavaScript and html.  I'd appreciate any comments, proposed refactoring, or criticism.

I have a fiddle of it in use [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sheldonj/awgaM/11/)

Here's the code:

```
(function (window, $, undefined) {
    "use strict";
    var ab = window.ab = window.autoBinder = {},
        elements;

    ab.exportSymbol = function (publicPath, object) {
        var tokens = publicPath.split("."),
            target = window,
            i;

        for (i = 0; i < tokens.length - 1; i++) {
            target = target[tokens[i]];
        }
        target[tokens[tokens.length - 1]] = object;
    };

    ab.exportProperty = function (owner, publicName, object) {
        owner[publicName] = object;
    };

    ab.extensions = (function () {
        return {
            datePicker: function (element) {
                var params = {
                    minDate: 0,
                    showButtonPanel: false
                },
            e = $(element);

                if (e.data("mindate") !== undefined) {
                    params.minDate = e.data("mindate");
                }

                if (e.data("showpanel") !== undefined) {
                    params.showButtonPanel = e.data("showpanel");
                }

                e.datepicker(params);
            }
        };
    })();

    ab.hookups = (function () {
        return {
            make: function (value, element) {
                if (ab.extensions[value]) {
                    ab.extensions[value](element);
                }
            },
            publish: function (value, $element) {
                if (!value) {
                    return;
                }

                $element.change(function () {
                    $element.trigger(value, $element);
                });
            },
            subscribe: function (value, $element) {
                var trigger = $element.data("trigger");
                if (trigger === undefined) {
                    throw "Found Subscribe without Trigger.";
                }

                if (!ab.extensions[trigger]) {
                    throw "Found Subscribe without Trigger.";
                }

                $(document).bind(value, function (event, htmlElement) {
                    ab.extensions[trigger](event, htmlElement, $element);
                });
            }
        };
    })();

    ab.exportSymbol("ab.extensions.datePicker", ab.extensions.datePicker);
    ab.exportSymbol("ab.hookups.make", ab.hookups.make);
    ab.exportSymbol("ab.hookups.publish", ab.hookups.publish);
    ab.exportSymbol("ab.hookups.subscribe", ab.hookups.subscribe);


    $(window).load(function () {
        elements = $("*").filter(function () {
            var data = $(this).data(),
                p;
            if (data === undefined) {
                return false;
            }
            for (p in data) {
                if (data.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        });

        elements.each(function () {
            var obj = $(this),
                data = obj.data(),
                p;

            for (p in data) {
                if (data.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                    if (ab.hookups[p]) {
                        ab.hookups[p](data[p], obj);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
} (window, jQuery));

// #region Example of Extending extensions
    window.ab.extensions.effectiveDateChanged = function (event, triggerElement, subscribedElement) {
        var $element = jQuery(triggerElement);
        subscribedElement.val("Value set to: " + $element.val());
    };

window.ab.extensions.dropDownChanged = function(event, triggerElement, subscribedElement) {
    var $element = jQuery(triggerElement),
        value = $element.val();

    if (value === "") {
        subscribedElement.attr("disabled", "disabled");
        subscribedElement.html("");
        return;
    }

    subscribedElement.removeAttr("disabled");
    subscribedElement.html("<option>" + value + "</option>");
};
// #endregion
```

Answer (score 3):

Update here: http://jsfiddle.net/5ej8G/3/ (code is also pasted below)

Main suggestions:

- your exportSymbol function can be refactored to handle an array of publicPaths and Objects.
- The subscribe conditions can be consolidated since they throw the same message.
- check your parameters before using.  typeOf checks don't work well with all objects, but there are techniques to have them work with all objects.  One from Angus Croll(http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/fixing-the-javascript-typeof-operator/) is included in the link above.
- Explicitly state which elements you want your code to act on, maybe by passing in a parameter object.  doing a $("*"), on medium to large pages (with lots of dom elements) can be a performance hit.

```
(function (window, $, undefined) {
    "use strict";
    var ab = window.ab = window.autoBinder = {},
        elements,

        toType = function(obj) {
      return ({}).toString.call(obj).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase()
    };
    //can handle an array of publicPaths and objects
    ab.exportSymbols = function (paramArray) {
        var tokens,
            target = window,
            i,
            index,
            len,
            limit,
            exportSymbol;
        if(toType(paramArray) !== 'array') { 
            throw "You must pass an array into this function.";            
        }

        //Export Symbol now becomes a inner helper function
        exportSymbol = function(pubPath, obj) {
            tokens = pubPath.split(".");
            lastIndex = tokens.Length;

            for (i = 0; i < lastIndex ; i++) {
                target = target[tokens[i]];
            }
            target[tokens[lastIndex]] = obj;
        };

        //validate and run helper function on each object in array
        for(index= 0, len=paramArray.length; i < len; i++) {
            if(toType(paramArray.publicPath) !== 'string' 
               || toType(paramArray.publicPath) !== 'object') {
                    continue;
            }
            exportSymbol(paramArray[index].publicPath, paramArray[index].obj);            
        }
    };

    ab.exportProperty = function (owner, publicName, object) {
        owner[publicName] = object;
    };

    ab.extensions = function () {
        return {
            datePicker: function (element) {
                var params = {
                    minDate: 0,
                    showButtonPanel: false
                },
            e = $(element);

                if (e.data("mindate") !== undefined) {
                    params.minDate = e.data("mindate");
                }

                if (e.data("showpanel") !== undefined) {
                    params.showButtonPanel = e.data("showpanel");
                }

                e.datepicker(params);
            }
        };
    }();

    ab.hookups = (function () {
        return {
            make: function (value, element) {

                if (ab.extensions[value]) {
                    ab.extensions[value](element);
                }
            },
            publish: function (value, $element) {

                if (!value) {
                    return;
                }

                $element.change(function () {
                    $element.trigger(value, $element);
                });
            },
            subscribe: function (value, $element) {
                var trigger = $element.data("trigger");

               //Conditions can be consolidate since they trow the same message
                if ((trigger === undefined) || !ab.extensions[trigger]) {
                    throw "Found Subscribe without Trigger.";
                }                

                $(document).bind(value, function (event, htmlElement) {
                    ab.extensions[trigger](event, htmlElement, $element);
                });
            }
        };
    })();

    //can pass in a an array of object instead of mutiple calls
    ab.exportSymbols([
                     {pubPath : "ab.extensions.datePicker", obj : ab.extensions.datePicker},
                     {pubPath : "ab.hookups.make"         , obj : ab.hookups.make},
                     {pubPath : "ab.hookups.publish"      , obj : ab.hookups.publish},
                     {pubPath : "ab.hookups.subscribe"    , obj : ab.hookups.subscribe}
    ]);


    $(window).load(function () {
        elements = $("*").filter(function () {
            var data = $(this).data(),
                p;
            if (data === undefined) {
                return false;
            }
            for (p in data) {
                if (data.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        });

        elements.each(function () {
            var obj = $(this),
                data = obj.data(),
                p;

            for (p in data) {
                if (data.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                    if (ab.hookups[p]) {
                        ab.hookups[p](data[p], obj);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
} (window, jQuery));

//  Example Extending extensions
    window.ab.extensions.effectiveDateChanged = function (event, triggerElement, subscribedElement) {
        var $element = jQuery(triggerElement);
        subscribedElement.val("Value set to: " + $element.val());
    };

window.ab.extensions.dropDownChanged = function(event, triggerElement, subscribedElement) {
    var $element = jQuery(triggerElement),
        value = $element.val();

    if (value === "") {
        subscribedElement.attr("disabled", "disabled");
        subscribedElement.html("");
        return;
    }

    subscribedElement.removeAttr("disabled");
    subscribedElement.html("<option>" + value + "</option>");
};
```